# The header value of the struts2 select tag does not repopulate when validation fails

Tags: jsp, struts2, struts-validation, struts-tags, repopulation

I have the following `<s:select>` tag for a drop down list of states and a default state determined by `defaultStateId`.

```
<s:select name = "stateId" 
            id = "chooseState" 
          list = "stateList" 
       listKey = "codeId" 
     listValue = "shortDescription"  
         value = "defaultStateId"  
     headerKey = "0" 
   headerValue = "-Select-" 
         class = "form-control" 
      tabindex = "12"/>
```

If the user selects any state and the validation fails the state they chose repopulates on the page when the error is displayed on the page (which is what I want).

But if they choose the `headerValue` `-Select-`, it does not repopulate even though the `stateId` is `0` when the `validate()` method runs.

Why does the `value="defaultId"` override the choice of `-Select-` but not the choice of any state?  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Does it work if you use `-1` instead of `0` as headerKey ?

Comment: Is `defaultStateId` fixed or is it dynamically calculated in the `execute()` method ?

Comment: I found the issue thanks to your questions.  The getDefaultStateId() method returns the defaultStateId from a code table if the id value is 0 so it over writes the '-Select-` option.  Thanks!.

Answer (score -1):

Change headerKey to "-1". That should fix it.

Comment: Some more explanations would be very nice.